# Usar variáveis de fora da função

Tags: php

Eu estou estudando php7 e vi em algum lugar que agora é possível usar variáveis externas da função, mais que estão no mesmo arquivo. Pelo que me lembro era algo assim:

```
<?php 
$agua = '1 Litro';

function listaDeCoisas($item1,$item2) use $agua{
   return 'Lista: '.$item1.','.$item2.', Agua: '. $agua;
}
```

Quero saber se isso é realmente possível e como usar!

Answer (score 6):

Isto já era possível em versões mais antigas. Você pode usar o escopo `global`.

Exemplo:

```
$msg = "Olá!";

function exibeMsg()
{
    global $msg;
    echo $msg;
}

exibeMsg(); // Imprimirá "Olá!"
```

Você pode acessar a variável de "fora" da função, independente de ela estar no arquivo em questão ou em um arquivo incluído.

Answer (score 2):

Acho que você quer fazer isso com funções anônimas. Conhecida também como *clousures*, estão disponíveis desde o [PHP 5.3](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/functions.anonymous.php):

```
$agua = '1 Litro';

$garraga = function ($item1,$item2) use ($agua) {
   return 'Lista: '.$item1.','.$item2.', Agua: '. $agua;
}

echo $garrafa();
```

O que entrou de novo no PHP 7 que é parecido com isso são as [classes anônimas](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.anonymous.php). Elas são úteis para criar classes específicas e que provavelmente não serão reutilizadas.

```
// PHP 5
class Logger
{
    public function log($msg)
    {
        echo $msg;
    }
}

$util->setLogger(new Logger());

// Opção no PHP 7+ 
$util->setLogger(new class {
    public function log($msg)
    {
        echo $msg;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

A palavra-chave `use` só é permitida em funções anonimas ou clousures como no exemplo abaixo;

```
$message = 'Hello';

$example = function () use ($message) {
    var_dump($message);
};
$example();
```

## [Veja funcionando no Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5606989540c501a077ddf5fe41703693fb56f38c)